# Amazon SNS Text Messaging

Tags: amazon-sns

I'm using Amazon SNS for sending Text Message blasts to subscribers on my site.  I would like to be able to have a different short code to send from, assigned if possible to one of my User accounts which have already been created and which have their own Key and Secret for use with the SNS API.

Where do I go in the AWS Console to set this up?  Is this possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.  Take a look at [the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_shortcodes.html).  You ultimately need to create an SNS Limit Increase case with Amazon support.  But make sure you follow the [SMS Pricing doc](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/sms-pricing/) because it's not cheap or quick:

> Amazon SNS now supports dedicated short codes for the US destinations.
>   Each dedicated short code is $995 per month. You are billed for your
>   dedicated short code addresses at the end of each month along with any
>   other Amazon SNS text message sending charges you incur.
>
> The United States Short Codes will incur a one-time setup fee of $650.
>   Carrier approval may take 8-12 weeks (or longer), and your short code
>   may not be fully live with all US carriers during this period.
>
> To request a dedicated short code, open a dedicated short code limit
>   increase case in Support Centre.

Comment: you are correct, thank you.  Unfortunately, the pricing for this is enough of a deterrent to go another route completely.

Comment: @Phil - another option is a service like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) (no affiliation) that would allow you to at least use different phone numbers, even if they're not short codes.  It's not free but, depending on your volume, it's pretty cheap.

Comment: yep, that is what we ended up doing.